# How do I convert .bin and .cue files to .iso for FREE on a Mac?

Tags: macos, file-conversion

I have some .bin & .cue files I'd like to convert .iso. I'm looking for a freeware program that will do this. Any suggestions.

NOTE I'm aware that VLC is supposed to be able to open these types of files but for some strange reason it's not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On a Mac, you can mount an iso/dmg file and then "open disc" from VLC to view it (Assuming the image is a DVD/VCD). bin/cue specifically should be converted like sheepz said with bchunk.

FYI to mount an iso, use the disc utility app or from the command line - 'hdiutil mount myiso.iso'.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo port install bchunk
bchunk IMAGE.bin IMAGE.cue OUTPUTIMAGE.iso
```

I don't this is what you are looking for though.
VLC should have support for SVCD and VCD files, but are you certain that these files are SVCD and VCD?